# debugger freezes on X (arm)

Tags: qt, debugging, xcb, qdbus

I am developing an application for `Olimex A20` with Qt 5.7. This app needs to run on X. If I just run the application it works perfectly fine. The issue is with the debuging - debugger freezes. This is the stack trace I see when I interrupt the debugger.

This is the line of code where the debugger is waiting for something to happen (`qwaitcondition_unix.cpp` - line 143).

`code = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);`

This is the main stack trace from thread #1

```
1  __libc_do_syscall                                                                       0xb5dd6514 
2  pthread_cond_wait * *GLIBC_2.4                                                          0xb5dd1da6 
3  QWaitConditionPrivate::wait                       qwaitcondition_unix.cpp          143  0xb63a7a44 
4  QWaitCondition::wait                              qwaitcondition_unix.cpp          215  0xb63a7a44 
5  QSemaphore::acquire                               qsemaphore.cpp                   143  0xb63a2dba 
6  QMetaObject::activate                             qobject.cpp                      3708 0xb6506c6e 
7  QMetaObject::activate                             qobject.cpp                      3602 0xb6506fee 
8  QDBusConnectionManager::connectionRequested       moc_qdbusconnectionmanager_p.cpp 141  0xb3baf2a0 
9  QDBusConnectionManager::connectToBus              qdbusconnection.cpp              225  0xb3b6b37e 
10 QDBusConnectionManager::busConnection             qdbusconnection.cpp              134  0xb3b6b488 
11 QDBusConnection::sessionBus                       qdbusconnection.cpp              1195 0xb3b6c058 
12 DBusConnection::DBusConnection                    dbusconnection.cpp               73   0xb3e08a4c 
13 QSpiAccessibleBridge::QSpiAccessibleBridge        bridge.cpp                       66   0xb3dff070 
14 QXcbIntegration::accessibility                    qxcbintegration.cpp              337  0xb3dc563c 
15 platformAccessibility                             qaccessible.cpp                  485  0xb6a4ae34 
16 QAccessible::isActive                             qaccessible.cpp                  791  0xb6a4ae34 
17 QQuickTextInputPrivate::emitCursorPositionChanged qquicktextinput.cpp              4206 0xb6eb5fde 
18 QQuickTextInputPrivate::moveCursor                qquicktextinput.cpp              3264 0xb6eb9d76 
19 QQuickTextInputPrivate::setCursorPosition         qquicktextinput_p_p.h            407  0xb6eb9e2a 
20 QQuickTextInput::setReadOnly                      qquicktextinput.cpp              682  0xb6eb9e2a 
21 QQuickTextInput::qt_static_metacall               moc_qquicktextinput_p.cpp        1180 0xb6f593e8 
22 QQuickTextInput::qt_metacall                      moc_qquicktextinput_p.cpp        1257 0xb6f59cf8 
23 QQmlPropertyPrivate::write                        qqmlproperty.cpp                 1254 0xb68a648a 
24 QQmlPropertyPrivate::writeValueProperty           qqmlproperty.cpp                 1183 0xb68a7594 
25 QQmlBinding::write                                qqmlbinding.cpp                  333  0xb68f38da 
26 QQmlBinding::update                               qqmlbinding.cpp                  197  0xb68f46fc 
27 QQmlObjectCreator::finalize                       qqmlobjectcreator.cpp            1202 0xb68faf92 
28 QQmlComponentPrivate::complete                    qqmlcomponent.cpp                926  0xb68a861e 
29 QQmlComponentPrivate::completeCreate              qqmlcomponent.cpp                962  0xb68a8698 
30 QQmlComponent::create                             qqmlcomponent.cpp                788  0xb68a85ac 
31 QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::_q_finishLoad       qqmlapplicationengine.cpp        136  0xb68f55fc 
32 QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::startLoad           qqmlapplicationengine.cpp        115  0xb68f57a4 
33 QQmlApplicationEngine::load                       qqmlapplicationengine.cpp        260  0xb68f57de 
34 main                                              main.cpp                         50   0x1fd60
```

This is thread #6

```
1 __libc_do_syscall                0xb5dd6514 
2 pthread_cond_wait * *GLIBC_2.4   0xb5dd1da6 
3 _mali_osu_lock_wait              0xb61ec7fe 
4 __egl_worker_thread              0xb61e7096 
5 start_thread                     0xb5dcd5dc 
6 ??  

                         0xb5ffd71c
```

Anyone came across this issue? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: A long shot perhaps but... is it just the debugger that freezes or is it the entire display apart from the pointer?  If so is it possible that your application has a mouse/keyboard grab active when the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: It fails deeply in the bowels of the accessibility layer. One workaround might be to disable DBus support in your copy of Qt.

Comment: @KubaOber, Thanks for the tip. How do I do that please? I've cross compiled Qt with DBus support. It works fine if I just run normally i.e., not debugging.

Comment: Try cross-compiling another copy with DBus disabled, then. It probably is a Qt bug of some sort, but since it only seems to rear its ugly head in debugging, you might work around that way.